# Is possible with Google OAuth consent window leave the user select with permission they want with checkboxes?

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gdprconsentform, react-oauth

Currently in a project that I'm working we use Google Workspace for an internal app. We want to access to the email of some users, but not all. We investigate about omit some scopes for some user but wasn't possible.

We are using the Google OAuth 2.0, setting up the `gmail.readonly` on the scope param, but we want the user(company workers) picks which permission they allow to grant access. The current consent window looks like this:

[image: consent window image without checkboxes]

We want something like this:

[image: consent window image with checkboxes]

We are using `useGoogleLogin` from `@react-oauth/google` for login, like this way:

```
const login = useGoogleLogin({
    onSuccess: (codeResponse) => {
      getApiAccessToken(codeResponse);
    },
    scope:
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    flow: 'auth-code',
    enable_serial_consent: false,
    onError: () => {
      handleError();
    },
  });
```

Idk if we need to setup an additional thing there, but based on the docs of [react-oauth/google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google?activeTab=readme) looks like everything it's ok.

We also tried to add the `include_granted_scopes: false` param to `useGoogleLogin` but apparently is not related. All the flow works as expected, we gets the authorization in the backend and request the access token and so on, we only want to leave to the user decide if the want or not share the gmail data or not.

Answer (score 0):

> We investigate about omit some scopes for some user but wasn't possible.

This is possible if you ask for the user ID or email (`openid` or `email` scopes) before asking for additional scopes. You can make decisions based on the email or ID the user shared with you.

If you need to enable granular permissions, you can set your client to be external (instead of org internal). If you still need to make sure that only users within a certain workspace domain will grant access to your app, one possible way to do that may be with the [hd param.](https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect#hd-param)

Comment: Thanks @user2705223 for your answer.

So, basically we should try to login only with `openid` or `email` scope, validate these data and after that, request additional permissions?

So, the granular permissions only works for external consent?